# Call WCF asynchronous method with reflection

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection, asynchronous, .net-4.0

I have a WPF client which references a WCF service (everything with framework 4.0). The asynchronous methods have been generated, and I would like to call them dynamically with reflection. I know how to do it with synchronous methods but I do not know where to pass the callback for async call.

```
MethodInfo mi= type.GetMethod(methodName, new Type[] { typeof(string) });
mi.Invoke(instance, null);
// How can I use a callback from here ?
```

The method signature of the method I try to invoke :

```
public void GetAuthorisedDatabasesAsync(string username)
```

Comment: What's the signature of the method you're trying to invoke?

Comment: the method is : public void GetAuthorisedDatabasesAsync(string username)

Comment: Then you'll need to look at the class definition to see how to listen for completion; there is likely an event that is fired upon completion.